# tengo un error en la parte de etiqueta form

Tags: javascript, angular

1.tengo este error en la aprte de form casi penultima linia .Unexpected closing tag "form".
It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tagsngtsc(-995002)
```

Acepto los términos y condiciones
Acepto los términos y condiciones
<mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls.aceptaTerminos.errors?.required">
Debes aceptar los términos y condiciones

````
        <div class="text-center mt-2">
          <button
            mat-fab
            color="primary"
            [disabled]="!registerForm.valid"
            class="mat-elevation-z6"
            (click)="onRegisterFormSubmit(registerForm.value)"
            >
            <mat-icon>person_add</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form> <!-- aquio el error -->
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-card>
<ngx-spinner type="ball-scale-multiple"></ngx-spinner>```
````